# After reinstalling windows Outlook is not syncing folders other than inbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, microsoft-outlook-2013

**Background**

On my outlook panel I had the following folders:

- The default Folders: Inbox, Sent, Draft etc
- Personal / Custom created folders: Ex. "Sustenance", "Reference", "Too Long Read Later" etc.

I had a lot of rules setup to sort mails into these folders.. Until I had to reinstall Windows > Reinstall Office 2013.

**The Problem**

After reinstall Outlook is syncing emails. But it is not creating these folders automatically. I'm guessing that these folders must have been created in my Profile on the server.

**Question**

How can I get Outlook to create these folders again? When I try to sync it only syncs my Inbox folder.

Comment: If you are using IMAP and those folders are on the server, you may need to subscribe to those folders. What e-mail protocol are using to connect to your e-mail: Exchange, IMAP, POP3?

Comment: I found the solution to this problem. I just don't remember where exactly it was. Somewhere inside Outlook> Account settings>  there was an option where I could select which folders to sync. Only the Inbox was checked. So I manually checked the other Folder names and then the next sync recreated all my Folders automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this is an exchange account as you refer to a server? It should recreate the folders automatically - check Mail in control panel, select Email accounts and then double click the account in question. There is a slider that sets what mail to keep offline - slide it all the way to the right and click Next and finish. Reopen Outlook and see. If still not, go back there and off tick the Use Cached Exchange box, finish it and reopen Outlook again. If the latter shows the folders, then you need to go delete your OST and SRS files in your profile folder, re-enable Cached mode and reopen Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

You have IMAP folder. There should be an option to view/edit Subscribed Folders.

- In Mail, in the Navigation Pane, right-click the top folder for your IMAP account.
- Click IMAP Folders.
- Click Query.
- Click a folder, and then click
  Subscribe or Unsubscribe.

Source: [Choose which IMAP folders appear](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Choose-which-IMAP-account-folders-appear-in-Outlook-32103602-a568-4499-9d25-54fe236aee6a?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)